# pass viewModel to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

i have two mapping classes and i have wrap them into another class so i can send it to view as wrap two model but i am getting following error.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DatabaseLayer.TableMappings.FeeScheme]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DatabaseLayer.ViewModels.FeeSchemeZone]'.
```

now in controller i am passing list of data to view aswell... i guess is conflicting here somewhere as i am sending list...

is it better to use partial view over ViewModel????

### wrapper class

```
 public class FeeSchemeZone
{
    public FeeZone _FeeZone;
    public FeeScheme _FeeScheme;
}
 //where FeeZone and FeeScheme are separate mapping classes
```

### Controller

```
  public ActionResult FeeScheme()
    {
        var query_result = FeeScheme_UOF.GetAllFeeScheme();

        return View(query_result.ToList());

    }
```

### View

```
@model IEnumerable<DatabaseLayer.ViewModels.FeeSchemeZone>
```

Comment: var query_result = FeeScheme_UOF.GetAllFeeScheme(); does that return List<FeeScheme> or List<FeeSchemeZone>? you view is expecting List<FeeShcemeZone>, if you are passing List<FeeScheme> then it is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
@model IEnumerable<DatabaseLayer.ViewModels.FeeSchemeZone>
```

That needs to be -

```
@model IEnumerable<DatabaseLayer.ViewModels.FeeScheme>
```

And regarding your questions about PartialViews, if you get re-usability of views, then definitely make it into PartialView.